# Create Proportion Function from Count Tables with Different Variable Names

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Problem: I have a survey with 100 questions. These have a potential to have 5 types of responses, which I have grouped and tallied into separate tables (in a list). Each table has a different number of columns, with different variable names.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
tbl1 <-   tribble(~"stakeholder", ~"Question", ~"1-Little", ~"2",   ~"3",   ~"4-Much",  ~"Do not know/ Not applicable", ~"no_response",
        "SH_1", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,
        "SH_2", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,
        "SH_3", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,
        "SH_4", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,
)

tbl2 <- tribble(~"stakeholder", ~"Question", ~"1-Little",   ~"2",   ~"3",   ~"4-Much", ~"5-MuchMuch",   ~"Do not know/ Not applicable", ~"no_response",
                "SH_1", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,2,
                "SH_2", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,2,
                "SH_3", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,2,
                "SH_4", "QUESTION 2",   2,  1,  4,  8, 1,   1,2
)
```

**Problem: How to create proportion counts based on sum?**
I need to create proportion tables based on the total number of responses for each question.

I create the above counts in the sample tables from character responses by tallying, based upon a grouped variable. I note that I have 6 different ways I'll be grouping and reproducing the graphics and tables (close to 600 needed in total!):

```
    tally_function <- function(tbl) {
  tbl %>% 
  gather(key = Question, value = Response,
         12:length(.)) %>% 
  group_by(stakeholder, Question, Response) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  spread(Response, n, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(stakeholder, Question, everything(), no_response = `<NA>`) %>% 
    arrange(Question)

}
```

The previous function I used called on individual column names to produce the sums, but this won't work here as the column names are different in each table:

```
Prop_Function_Group1 <- function(tbl){
  tbl %>% 
    summarise(`Number of Responses (Count)` = sum(`1-Little` + `2`+`Do not know/ Not applicable`+
                                            `3`+`4-Much` + no_response, na.rm = TRUE),
              `1-Little`= sum(`1-Little`/`Number of Responses (Count)`, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
              `2` = sum(`2` / `Number of Responses (Count)`, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
              `Do not know/ Not applicable` = sum(`Do not know/ Not applicable` / `Number of Responses (Count)`, na.rm = TRUE)* 100,
              `3` = sum(`3` / `Number of Responses (Count)`, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
              `4-Much` = sum(`4-Much` / `Number of Responses (Count)`, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
              `no_response` = sum(no_response / `Number of Responses (Count)`, na.rm = TRUE) * 100
    ) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2) %>% 
    arrange(desc(`Number of Responses (Count)`))
}
```

Currently, I have this, but believe I will need some kind of ifelse / case_when() loop based upon names(tbl), but am really new at programming and am not sure where to start. The col names within the summarise function need to be the same as the names of the input table which they're summarising as well.

```
    prop_function <- function(tbl){
  tbl %>% 
  summarise(`Number of Responses` = sum(3:length(.), na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

I don't need an entire solution, any small ideas and contributions are helpful. If this is a duplicated question type, appreciated to be guided in the right direction.

I am also feeding these into a purr::map() + ggplot() afterwards, so appreciate if solutions are somewhat tidyverse-friendly.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that continues using dplyr/tidyverse and mirrors the format/structure of your output from `Prop_Function_Group1(tbl1)`. However this function should be able to be applied to other tables of the form you described.

```r
library(tidyverse)

prop_function <- function(tbl){
tbl_counts <- tbl %>% 
  summarise_if(is.double, ~sum(.x))

tbl_counts %>% 
  mutate_all(~100 * .x / sum(tbl_counts)) %>%
  mutate(`Number of Responses (Count)` = sum(tbl_counts)) %>% 
  mutate_all(round, digits = 2) %>% 
  select(length(.), everything()) # move last col to first
}

list(tbl1, tbl2) %>% 
  map(prop_function)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   `Number of Resp~ `1-Little`   `2`   `3` `4-Much` `Do not know/ N~
#>              <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1               68       11.8  5.88  23.5     47.1             5.88
#> # ... with 1 more variable: no_response <dbl>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 8
#>   `Number of Resp~ `1-Little`   `2`   `3` `4-Much` `5-MuchMuch`
#>              <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1               76       10.5  5.26  21.0     42.1         5.26
#> # ... with 2 more variables: `Do not know/ Not applicable` <dbl>,
#> #   no_response <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for this, it puts me on the right track. One challenge is that I believe the mutate_all() is removing the "stakeholder" which is actually a flexible grouping variable I'll be replacing with others. I've added my own "tbl_counts" function in my question, which I'm currently trying to integrate into your approach. Thanks for the very comprehensive answer

Comment: Glad that was a helpful starting place.  The `stakeholder` variable was removed at my `summarise_if` step.  My output was based on the output from `Prop_Function_Group1(tbl1)` (prior to your adding the `tally_function`).  I'd suggest adding what your intended output should look like.

Comment: yeah, that's when I started looking for alternatives and found out via another question asked about nesting mutate(map(select_if))) which I never would have thought of myself! And you're right, I will do that now (and in the future make sure to add more detail into the question as to what exact output I need). Cheers @bryan-shalloway

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by @bryan-shalloway gave above put me on the right track - the main changes made here are that this version maintains the grouping variable names by nesting map() operations within a mutate():

```
  proportion_function <- function(tbl){


  tbl_counts <- tbl %>%
    gather(key = Question, value = Response,
           12:length(.)) %>% 
    group_by(Region, Question, Response) %>% 
    tally %>% 
    spread(Response, n, fill = 0) %>% 
    select(Region, Question, everything(), no_response = `<NA>`) %>%
    arrange(Question)

  tbl_counts %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% select_if(is.numeric) 
                      %>% mutate(count = sum(rowSums(.))))) %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% select_if(is.numeric) 
                      %>% mutate_all(funs((. / count) * 100 )))) %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% select_if(is.numeric)
                      %>% mutate_all(round, digits = 2))) %>%
    unnest()
}
```